# Invalid syntax for the line: import Start background_rc, which is made by qt-designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I designed at qtdesigner a mainwindow converted the .ui into .py
When I run it I get an SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the line:

```
import Start background_rc
```

I have no idea what 'module' that should be and how I can fix it.

Comment: can you upload your code ?

Comment: `import` should be lowercase. And you can't have a space in the module name.

Comment: @ Barmar sorry the upercase is a writing mistake in my code it is lowercase. The space is made by pyuic5 with witch i converted the data from qtdesigner. Even when i write it together it doesen't work.

Comment: @ddor254 Im new on stackoverflow, how can i comment my code? He's to long for a comment.

Comment: Is your resource file by any case named "Start background.rc"? If yes, then, rename it to something without spaces.

Comment: @icwebndev thank you I found it. My .qrc file I used to add my background picture was named like that. Now I changed it into Startbackground but now I get an error: no Module named "Startbackground_rc". The _rc is added by qt.

Comment: Have you converted your resource file with `pyrcc5`?

Comment: @Chris like pyuic you must use `pyrcc5 Startbackground.qrc -o Startbackground_rc.py`

Comment: Thank all of you I never read that I have to convert the resource file as well. Now it does work :)